# Is there some SVG processor?

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-browser

I am searching for a cross-browser client-side library to build SVG a similar way SASS/LESS/SCSS build CSS.

Do you know something like that?

Answer (score 1):

There is SnapSVG. It is not a preprocessor but Snap.svg is designed for modern browsers and therefore supports the newest SVG features like masking, clipping, patterns, full gradients, groups, and more.

http://snapsvg.io/

SnapSVG Demos:

http://snapsvg.io/demos/

Getting Started with SnapSVG:

http://snapsvg.io/start/

SnapSVG Docs:

http://snapsvg.io/docs/

Comment: This is something like Raphaël: http://raphaeljs.com/ thank you for sharing.

Comment: @t33st33r SnapSVG is made by the same person (Dmitry Baranovskiy) that created Raphaël.js, But SVG is his newer SVG JavaScript library to be used with SVG. But both are great for working with SVG cross browser with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a solution for generating SVGs on the server. Frankly there doesn't seem to be much out there for you.

I did a bit of googling, and the best I came up with was [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/love-generating-svg-javascript-move-to-server/) which describes using PhantomJS to run the standard client-side libraries on the server. It's not the answer you're looking for, but it's the best I've been able to find.